# Using Python regex to ignore `:` from string

Tags: python, regex

I am new to the world of `regex.` Hence, I'm sorry if this might sound basic. I have finished reading regex community and Lopez's book on Mastering regex for Python to ensure that I am not posting beginner-level question.

I have scraped data from a wiki (for learning), and I am trying to extract strings

a) that start with `\wiki`

b) that don't contain `:`

Here's the text:

```
/wiki/Template:Kevin_Bacon
/wiki/Category:Best_Miniseries_or_Television_Movie_Actor_Golden_Globe_winners
/wiki/Al_Pacino
/wiki/Paul_Giamatti
/wiki/Kevin_Costner
/wiki/Kevin_Costner
/wiki/Michael_Douglas
/wiki/Mark_Ruffalo
/wiki/Idris_Elba
/wiki/Bryan_Cranston
/wiki/Alexander_Skarsg%C3%A5rd
/wiki/Biblioteca_Nacional_de_Espa%C3%B1a
/wiki/Template:Kevin_Bacon
https://hy.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D5%94%D6%87%D5%AB%D5%B6_%D4%B2%D5%A5%D5%B5%D6%84%D5%B8%D5%B6
```

The output must be grouped i.e. I should get a list (or tuple) of these strings:

```
/wiki/Al_Pacino
/wiki/Paul_Giamatti
/wiki/Kevin_Costner
/wiki/Kevin_Costner
/wiki/Michael_Douglas
/wiki/Mark_Ruffalo
/wiki/Idris_Elba
/wiki/Bryan_Cranston
/wiki/Alexander_Skarsg%C3%A5rd
/wiki/Biblioteca_Nacional_de_Espa%C3%B1a
```

Here are my attempts at extracting the strings:

**a) Using negative look-ahead:**
The idea is to not select string that is followed by `:`
`r^/wiki/.*(?!:).*`
However, above code still selects strings with `:` i.e. `/wiki/Template:Kevin_Bacon`

**b) Force regex to not select `:`**
`^/wiki/.*[^:].*`
However, above code still selects strings with `:` i.e. `/wiki/Template:Kevin_Bacon`

**c) Use quantifier to specify that `:` should occur zero times**
`^/wiki/.*:{0}.*$`
However, above code still selects strings with `:` i.e. `/wiki/Template:Kevin_Bacon`

I have two questions:

a) I really like `regex`. Can someone please explain what's wrong with above tries?

b) How can I solve the problem using above approaches?

I am going to use `regex` module in python. As per SO's guidelines, I tried to debug `regex` on `regex101` website. Here's the link: https://regex101.com/r/Wt40Cz/1

I'd sincerely appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `^\/wiki\/[^:]+?$`

Comment: Many thanks. Do you mind explaining why you removed `.*` before and after "colon exclusion" i.e. `[^:]`. I am trying to learn the logic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ZaphoOxx no you don't

Comment: @Zapho: I don't think so because I am using raw string notation in python: `r" "`

Comment: @watchtower: When you try matching a regex, it gives all attempts to match the input text by any means. This .* in your regex was actually matching the : too due to which lines having : were also getting selected. You just had to slightly correct your regex like ran_0315 already said and modify it to ^/wiki/[^:]+$ This will match /wiki/ followed by any character except : The moment it finds a : after /wiki/ it will reject the input text

Comment: For those of us who are following these threads: I have corrected the three options above: `1. negative look-ahead:^/wiki/[a-zA-Z_]+(?!:)$`
`2. Exclude ":": ^/wiki/[^:]+?$`
`3. Quantifier: ^/wiki/[a-zA-Z_]+[:]{0}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is wrong.

```
^/wiki/.*[^:].*
```

is parsed as follows:

- `^`: match the start of the line
- `/wiki/`: match the literal sequence `/wiki/`
- `.*`: match zero or more of any character
- `[^:]`: match anything that isn't a `:`
- `.*`: match zero or more of any character

So it

1. matches the start of the line (ok)
2. matches the literal `/wiki/` (ok)
3. matches the entire rest of the line (uh-oh)
4. backtracks a character and matches "anything that isn't a `:`", as long as the last character isn't `:` (hmm...)
5. matches nothing, i.e. zero or more of any character

So your regex ends up matching the entire line because of `.*`, never even checking the `:` except at the end.

Now look at what the correct expression does

```
^\/wiki\/[^:]+$
```

- `^`: match the start of the line
- `/wiki/`: match the literal sequence `/wiki/`
- `[^:]+`: match one or more of anything that isn't a `:`
- `$`: match the end of the line

  1. matches the start of the line (ok)
  2. matches the literal `/wiki/` (ok)
  3. matches the entire rest of the line, unless it contains a `:` in which case it fails
  4. matches the end of the line

Hopefully that helps you break things down better. I highly recommend https://www.regex101.com for building and testing regular expressions (it has a Python-compatible regex mode), since it also includes an explanation of what the regex engine is doing step by step.

Edit: to answer your second question, I don't see another sane way to construct this expression. Don't use lookaheads or quantifiers, that's not what this is for.

Comment: thank you so much. I have spent embarrassing number of hours on this. I have one clarification: isn't it that `.*` will match `0 or more` characters until it hits `[^:]`, when it will backtrack and exclude that string altogether? I didn't understand your bullet # 3. If what you said is true, it shouldn't select the strings with `:`. From `regex101` link I posted, that isn't happening. I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @watchtower it matches the entire rest of the line because it greedily matches "zero or more characters". That is clearly the rest of the line! It only tries to backtrack after it can't match anything else. See [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap).

Comment: Shadowtalker : Thanks for sharing the link. It was extremely helpful. If you don't mind, I have one follow-up question: learning from the article, I modified my query to `^/wiki/.*?[^:]$`. The idea is that after finding `wiki`, we would do lazy matching until `:` is not found i.e. I'm ignoring any letters between `wiki` and `:`. However, this doesn't work either. Any thoughts? I'm personally learning a lot, and I'd appreciate your helping me.

Comment: @watchtower i recommend stepping through the expression at https://www.regex101.com to see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Try regex `^\/wiki\/[^:]*?$`

It will match the string that start with `/wiki/` and then this `[^:]*?` will match the characters without `:` until the end `$`

In your regex , `^/wiki/.*[^:].*$`, there were two `.*` so the `:` will escape with any one of the `.*`.So, `[^:]*` will be enough to capture everything

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/Wt40Cz/3)